# acceder a los archivos fisicos donde se guardan todas las bases de datos de mysql

Tags: mysql

¿donde estan los archivos fisicos con toda la informacion de las bases de datos mysql, en ubuntu? Es para recuperar la informacion en caso de que se estropee el ordenador y no sea posible acceder a mysql.

Comment: Si bien en tu publicación describes cual es tu intención, no has hecho ninguna pregunta y me temo que pueda terminar cerrada por su falta de precisión. No estaría mal que te des una vuelta por [ask]. Un saludo.

Comment: Si se estropea el ordenar, dificilmente puedas acceder a tus archivos, y por eso la mejor recomendacion es que hagas backups y los guardes en otro lado.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

El lugar suele ser: /var/lib/mysql pero para asegurarnos, debemos mirar el fichero my.cnf. Este fichero se encuentra en:

Ubuntu, Debian y derivados: /etc/mysql/my.cnf
Red Hat, Fedora y derivados: /etc/my.cnf
Allí podemos ver el valor de datadir. La forma concreta en que se almacenan los datos dependerá del motor de almacenamiento que uses: MyISAM, InnoDB, etc.

Comment: A no ser que esté usando windows. Una instalación en windows con XAMPP o WAMPP no va a tener la carpeta /var/lib/mysql. Hay una razón por la que en la comunidad no respondemos preguntas hasta que no tenemos los detalles.... y es que *înventarse* los detalles no suele generar respuestas útiles :) Te recomiendo leer [answer] y evitar responder preguntas hasta que conozcas los detalles y puedas responder con seguridad.

Comment: @Benito-B OP aclaro que es en Ubuntu...

Comment: de hecho estan en /var/lib/mysql pero probe a copiarlos de la antigua ubicacion a la nueva (parando antes el servidor) y ahora no funciona mysql.

Comment: Que error te da luego de cambiar la ubicación?